# looping through complicated nested dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a rather complex list of dictionaries with nested dictionaries and arrays. I am trying to figure out a way to either,

1. make the list of data less complicated and then loop through the
   raster points or,
2. find a way to loop through the array of raster points as is.

What I am ultimately trying to do is loop through all raster points within each polygon, perform a simple greater than or less than on the value assigned to that raster point (values are elevation values). If greater than a given value assign 1, if less than given value assign 0. I would then create a separate array of these 1s and 0s of which I can then get an average value.

I have found all these points (allpoints within pts), but they are in arrays within a dictionary within another dictionary within a list (of all polygons) at least I think, I could be wrong in the organization as dictionaries are rather new to me.

The following is my code:

```
import numpy as np

def mystat(x):

    mystat = dict()
    mystat['allpoints'] = x
    return mystat

stats = zonal_stats('acp.shp','myGeoTIFF.tif')

pts = zonal_stats('acp.shp','myGeoTIFF.tif', add_stats={'mystat':mystat})
```

[Link](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1EmFjd4Xtn6B7bxTfkPhIVeUBvyjXTazf?usp=sharing) to my documents. Any help or direction would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are using `rasterstats` package. You could try something like this:

```
threshold_value = 15  # You may change this threshold value to yours

for o_idx in range(0, len(pts)):
    data = pts[o_idx]['mystat']['allpoints'].data
    for d_idx in range(0, len(data)):
        for p_idx in range(0, len(data[d_idx])):
            # You may change the conditions below as you want
            if data[d_idx][p_idx] > threshold_value:
                data[d_idx][p_idx] = 1
            elif data[d_idx][p_idx] <= threshold_value:
                data[d_idx][p_idx] = 0;
```

It is going to update the data within the `pts` list